# LaTeX TikZ figure with straight rows and arrows, with subscripts

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I am new to the LaTeX programming and learned to make my first TikZ figure. My new objective is to make one with curves as in this graphic. Is there special package to be used for such a TikZ figure?

```
   \begin{tikzpicture}

  \node[main node] (1) {a};
  \node[main node] (2) [right of=1] {b};
  \node[main node] (3) [right of=2] {c};
  \node[main node] (4) [right of=3] {d};

  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge node [right] {} (2)
    (2) edge node [right] {} (3)
    \draw[->, line width= 1] (3) -- (4);
    (4) edge[bend right] node [left] {} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'd say it's possible to do that with plain Ti*k*Z. However you would have better answers if you showed what you tried so far so that people can help you where you're stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change angles as you want.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\def\a{1.5}
\path
(0,0) node (V) {$V$}
++(0:\a) node (A1) {$A_{(1)}$}
++(0:\a) node (M1) {$M_{(1)}$}
++(0:\a) node (L1) {$L_{(1)}$}
++(0:\a) node (A2) {$A_{(2)}$}
++(0:\a) node (M2) {$M_{(2)}$}
++(0:\a) node (L2) {$L_{(2)}$}
++(0:\a) node (dots) {$\cdots$}
++(0:\a) node (Y) {$Y$};

\draw[->] (V)--(A1);
\draw[->] (A1)--(M1);
\draw[->] (M1)--(L1);
\draw[->] (L1)--(A2);
\draw[->] (A2)--(M2);
\draw[->] (M2)--(L2);
\draw[->] (L2)--(dots);
\draw[->] (dots)--(Y);

\foreach \i in {M1,L1,A2,M2,L2}
\draw[->] (V) to[out=20,in=160] (\i);

\foreach \i in {L1,A2,M2,L2}
\draw[->] (A1) to[out=-20,in=-160] (\i);

\foreach \i in {A2,M2,L2}
\draw[->] (M1) to[out=-60,in=-120] (\i);

\foreach \i in {M2,L2}
\draw[->] (L1) to[out=60,in=120] (\i);

\draw[->] (A2) to[out=-80,in=-110] (L2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]